# Get friendly urls to work in Liferay

Tags: url, liferay, portlet

I wanted to enable friendly urls in liferay for my JSR-268 Portlets.

I configured the friendly url mapper as I was told in http://www.liferay.com/web/guest/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/FriendlyURLMapper but somehow this does not work for me.

What am I missing?

My `liferay-portlet.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE liferay-portlet-app PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Portlet Application 6.1.0//EN"     "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-portlet-app_6_1_0.dtd">
<liferay-portlet-app>
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>content</portlet-name>
    <friendly-url-mapper-class>com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.DefaultFriendlyURLMapper</friendly-url-mapper-class>
    <friendly-url-mapping>content</friendly-url-mapping>
    <friendly-url-routes>com/gentics/cr/portlet/content-url-routes.xml</friendly-url-routes>
    <instanceable>true</instanceable>
</portlet>
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>navigation</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <instanceable>true</instanceable>
</portlet>
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>search</portlet-name>
    <icon>/icon.png</icon>
    <instanceable>true</instanceable>
    <!-- header-portlet-css>/css/test.css</header-portlet-css>
    <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/test.js</footer-portlet-javascript-->
</portlet>
<!--role-mapper>
    <role-name>administrator</role-name>
    <role-link>Administrator</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
    <role-name>guest</role-name>
    <role-link>Guest</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
    <role-name>power-user</role-name>
    <role-link>Power User</role-link>
</role-mapper>
<role-mapper>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
    <role-link>User</role-link>
</role-mapper-->
</liferay-portlet-app>
```

My `content-url-routes.xml` looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE routes PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Friendly URL Routes 6.0.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-friendly-url-routes_6_0_0.dtd">

<routes>
<route>
    <pattern>/content/{contentid}</pattern>
</route>
<!-- route>
    <pattern>/{instanceId}/search/{filter}</pattern>
    <implicit-parameter name="do">search</implicit-parameter>
</route>
<route>
    <pattern>/{instanceId}/search/{filter}/{start}</pattern>
    <implicit-parameter name="do">search</implicit-parameter>
</route-->
</routes>
```

The urls rendered in the portlet is still: `http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home?p_auth=Yu81QQrj&p_p_id=content_WAR_genticsportlet_INSTANCE_R2HSaoL5RkHi&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-2&p_p_col_count=1&_content_WAR_genticsportlet_INSTANCE_R2HSaoL5RkHi_contentid=10007.33`

The URL was created using the follogwing code:

```java
PortletURL actionURL = response.createActionURL();
actionURL.setParameter("contentid", "10007.33");
```

It would be very nice if you could point me into the right direction...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your route should start with the part after `content` as `content` is already part of the generated URL. The value `<friendly-url-mapping>content</friendly-url-mapping>` is used for that.

```
<route>
    <pattern>/{contentid}</pattern>
</route>
```

Also, be sure to change the DTD to the latest one in your `*-url-routes.xml`.

```
<!DOCTYPE routes PUBLIC "-//Liferay//DTD Friendly URL Routes 6.1.0//EN" "http://www.liferay.com/dtd/liferay-friendly-url-routes_6_1_0.dtd">
```

Comment: I just tried that... but it still does not work. I assume that url mapping is working in both ways: the urls in the content shoul already be rendered as friendly urls... right?
Also could there be a problem with the instanceid / instanceable?

Comment: I had this exact doubt when I started exploring friendly-urls yesterday. After a lot debugging, turns out it does. I added a generic `<pattern>/</pattern>` to get it working. Try with `instanceable=false` to rule out `instanceid` issues.

Comment: Thanks... the generic <pattern>/</pattern> did at least change something. Now my URL looks like http://localhost:8080/web/guest/home/-/content/?p_auth=Yu81QQrj&p_p_lifecycle=1&_content_WAR_genticsportlet_INSTANCE_R2HSaoL5RkHi_contentid=10007.34 I also set instanceable to false but I still get the INSTANCE_R2... in the contentid parameter :/ I probably just have to play around a bit.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit clumsy and the documentation doesn't have all these nuances.

Answer (score 3):

Following on from Adarshr has answered you can also get rid of the /-/ part by creating your own class that extends DefaultFriendlyURLMapper and overrides the method 
isCheckMappingWithPrefix so you get:

```java
@Override
public boolean isCheckMappingWithPrefix() {     
    return false;
}
```

So you're URLs would be just be `http://community_name.com/web/group_name/page_name/content/contentId`. Then you set your class in the friendly-url-mapper-class tags. Which you can see an example of in this portlet project on GitHub:

`https://github.com/DevJonny/Liferay-6-Friendlier-Friendly-URL-Mapper`

~~ EDIT ~~

Thanks Prakash for pointing out that the old link didn't work.

Comment: thank you very much for linking the article... I'll have a look at it :)

Comment: No worries! :) let me know if you have any questions or suggestions for improving it!

Comment: Awesome tip! I will probably use this in my project.

Comment: Thanks @PrakashK I've updated my answer with a link to an example of this I have on GitHub

Answer (score 0):

I achieved to remove all params except the p_auth and my javax.portlet.action by using

```xml
<pattern>/myportlet</pattern>
<ignored-parameter name="p_p_lifecycle" />
<ignored-parameter name="p_p_state" />
<ignored-parameter name="p_p_mode" />
```

lifecycle, state and mode disappear from the url. But no way to remove the p_auth and the rest of the URL: